# Using list in Prolog DCG

Tags: prolog, dcg

I am trying to convert a Prolog predicate into DCG code. Even if I am familiar with grammar langage I have some troubles to understand how DCG works with lists and how I am supposed to use it.

Actually, this is my predicate :

```
cleanList([], []).
cleanList([H|L], [H|LL]) :-
    number(H),
    cleanList(L, LL),
    !.
cleanList([_|L], LL) :-
    cleanList(L, LL).
```

It is a simple predicate which removes non-numeric elements.
I would like to have the same behaviour writes in DCG.

I tried something like that (which does not work obviously) :

```
cleanList([]) --> [].
cleanList([H]) --> {number(H)}.
cleanList([H|T]) --> [H|T], {number(H)}, cleanList(T).
```

Is it possible to explain me what is wrong or what is missing ?

Thank you !

Comment: One big problem is `... --> [H|T], ...`. You want the DCG to read a sequence and the `[H|T]` has arbitrary length. Not sure why you included the `T` in that term. Your recursive call to `cleanList(T)` already scans `T` on the input.

Comment: Oh yeah I get it ! Thank you for you reply, I didn't understand how DCG read the sequence recursevely, now it is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of DCG notation is exactly to *hide*, or better, make implicit, the tokens list. So, your code should look like

```
cleanList([]) --> [].
cleanList([H|T]) --> [H], {number(H)}, cleanList(T).
cleanList(L) --> [H], {\+number(H)}, cleanList(L).
```

that can be made more efficient:

```
cleanList([]) --> [].
cleanList([H|T]) --> [H], {number(H)}, !, cleanList(T).
cleanList(L) --> [_], cleanList(L).
```

A style note: Prologgers do prefers to avoid camels :)

```
clean_list([]) --> [].
etc...
```

Also, I would prefer more compact code:

```
clean_list([]) --> [].
clean_list(R) --> [H], {number(H) -> R = [H|T] ; R = T}, clean_list(T).
```

Comment: I knew I was near of the answer, thank you for your precisions and your advices !

Comment: Sorry if this is obvious but has does one call  `clean_list/3` given above? If I want to clean `[1, 2, c, d, 5]` to `[1, 2, 5]` how would I call the definition given above to do that?

Comment: @MikeHarris: there is an ISO standard interface, [phrase/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=DCG): `?- phrase(clean_list(Clean),[1, 2, c, d, 5])`.